# Let $s$ be a simple function st. $s\le g+h$, show there exists simple functions $u\le g$, $v\le h$ st. $s=u+v$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $g,h$ be two functions and let $s$ be any simple function such that $s \le g+h$. Show there exists simple functions $u\le g$ and $v\le h$ such that $s=u+v$.

I have been thinking about this for a while without success. Can anyone provide some hint? Thank you!

Comment: You haven't specified the domain of your functions, but at least on some domains, I don't think this is true. Let $g(x)$ equal $1$ if $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is odd and $0$ if it is even, and let $h(x)$ have the complementary definition, so that $g(x)+h(x)=1$ identically; and take $s(x)=1$ identically.